# Delete comments in text file

Tags: python, regex, comments

I am trying to delete comments starting on new lines in a Python code file using Python code and regular expressions. For example, for this input:

```
first line

#description

hello my friend
```

I would like to get this output:

```
first line
hello my friend
```

Unfortunately this code didn't work for some reason:

```
with open(input_file,"r+") as f:
string = re.sub(re.compile(r'\n#.*'),"",f.read()))
f.seek(0)
f.write(string)
```

for some reason the output I get is the same as the input.

Comment: For one thing, it's incorrectly indented... Have you tried splitting it into smaller steps, and testing each one?

Comment: You are not comparing line by line I don't think. Try a multi-line match: `re.compile('^#.*', re.MULTILINE)`.

Comment: After fixing several syntax errors, I find that your program works precisely as expected. Please provide a short,  complete, otherwise-correct program that demonstrates the error. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no reason to call `re.compile` unless you save the result. You can always just use the regular expression text.

2) Seeking to the beginning of the file and writing there may cause problems for you if your replacement text is shorter than your original text. It is easier to re-open the file and write the data.

Here is how I would fix your program:

```
import re
input_file = 'in.txt'
with open(input_file,"r") as f:
    data = f.read()

data = re.sub(r'\n#.*', "", data)

with open(input_file, "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem right to start the regular expression with `\n`, and I don't think you need to use `re.compile` here.

In addition to that, you have to use the flag `re.M` to make the search on multiline

This will delete all lines that start with `#` and empty lines.

```
with open(input_file, "r+") as f:
    text = f.read()
    string = re.sub('^(#.*)|(\s*)$', '', text, flags=re.M)
    f.write(string)
```